# How do you check if a neural network has the exploding gradient problem?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

Given a formula for a particular RNN, is there a mathematical way to determine if it will suffer from the exploding/vanishing gradient problem?

For example I might try an RNNs in which the hidden state gets updated via:

$$h_{t+1} = \frac{1}{2}(h_t + \tanh( W[h_t,x_t] + b )$$

or

$$h_{t+1} = tanh(h_t + \tanh( W[h_t,x_t] + b )$$

where $x$ is the input, $W$ are weights and $b$ is a bias. How would I check if any of these formulas would suffer from the gradient problem?

Comment: I wouldn't engage it symbolically, that sounds like a losing proposition.  I like Eric Wan's diagrammatic gradient, and there is a very cheap way to bypass all the tricky calculus and treat it numerically.  I would make the "conjugate network", perturb the training values slightly and look at the actual values for the derivatives for being caught in the sand, or running off into the wilderness.